# How can I extract date from a .txt file which name contains date? (Scala)

Tags: regex, scala, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I have a .txt file as input for my beam programming project, using scala spotify scio.

`input= args.getOrElse("input", "/home/user/Downloads/trade-20181001.txt")`

How can I extract the date 2018-10-01 (1st October) from the file name? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above I would simply use the regex below. It searches for anything ending in 8 numbers followed by .txt.

```
(?<dateTime>\d{8})\.txt$

(?<dateTime> is the start of a named capture group.
\d{8} means exactly 8 digits.
) is the end of the named capture group.
\. means match the character . literally.
txt means match txt literally.
$ means that the string ends there and nothing comes after it.
```

If you cannot use named capture groups in your program you can always use the regex below without it and replace .txt out of it.

```
\d{8}\.txt$
```

Comment: Thank you! However if the file name is /home/user/Downloads/trade-20181001._cropped.txt do i do ```(?<dateTime>\d{8})\._cropped.txt$```

Comment: ` val regDate = "(?<dateTime>\d{8})\._cropped.txt$".r`

Comment: val date = regDate(input)